# Foundation - Change the colour of the hollow buttons

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm struggling to find the variables to how you can change the colouring of the hollow buttons that foundation provides.

At the moment I have to override the styling by doing the below:

```
&.hollow {
   border: 1px solid $clr-primary;
   color: $clr-primary;
}
```

I like having to do most of my styling changes in the foundation settings file instead of taking this approach so I don't have to write more CSS than I need.

Is there a variable that I am missing that I can apply these stylings to in the foundation settings?

Answer (score 1):

According the foundation wiki you find the variables here:

> All Foundation projects include a settings file, named _settings.scss. If you're using the CLI to create a Foundation for Sites project, you can find the settings file under scss/ (basic template) or src/assets/scss/ (ZURB template). If you're installing the framework standalone using Bower or npm, there's a settings file included in those packages, which you can move into your own Sass files to work with. 
>   — http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/sass.html

Changing the color palette: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/global.html#changing-the-color-palette

Comment: Yeah, I mean I already have this file included but there doesn't seem to be any variables in the file that you can change for hollow buttons.

Comment: Please tell me which version of foundation you are using and where you downloaded it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply read-up on the ZURB Foundation **SCSS Button MIXINS** which are explained at the bottom of [this page here >>](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/button.html)

Here are a few SCSS examples:

```css
div.pagenumber a.pagelink {
 @include button($expand:false, $background:$primary-color, $background-hover:auto, $color:auto, $style:solid);
 font-size: inherit;
 padding: 0.5em;
 margin: 0;
 border-radius: $global-radius;
}

div.pagenumber a.pagelink:hover {
 @include button($expand:false, $background:$primary-color, $background-hover:auto, $color:auto, $style:hollow);
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: inherit;
 padding: 0.5em;
 margin: 0;
 border-radius: $global-radius;
}

input.cancel {
 @include breakpoint(small) {
  @include button($expand:false, $background:$darkred, $background-hover:$crimson, $color:$white, $style:solid);
  font-size: 0.85rem;
 }
 @include breakpoint(medium) {font-size: 0.95rem;}
 @include breakpoint(large) {font-size: 1rem;}
}
```

Comment: That is useful but doesn't answer my question to if there is variables set specifically for hollow buttons in the foundation settings file. If there isn't then this would be the next best thing.

Comment: Of course it answers your question, exactly. Read the code. You create $variables for any colors you want. Then define whatever Button color scheme you like, using the @include button Mixin.